# Routing with Apache mod_rewrite linked files do not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this (and it works): Using PHP on Apache, I have set up htaccess to route all generic friendly/urls/with/slashes to index.php. Here's my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

For testing purposes, my index.php file contains really simple HTML, with a link to a JavaScript file that DOES exist at the proper path:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>A Test Page Goes Here</title>
    <script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The foo.js file which I'm calling has only the simplest diagnostic inside it:

```
console.log('howdy');
```

When I try accessing this page using its proper url, with no call to redirect, it works great. Like this:

```
http://myhost/index.php
```

When I try accessing this page using ONE url parameter, like this:

```
http://myhost/home
```

Everything still works as expected. The page appears, the JavaScript link works.

But when I try accessing the page using more url pieces, like this:

```
http://myhost/pages/home
```

I get two errors, like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Resource interpreted as Script but 
transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://myhost/home/foo.js".
```

And when I use the browser's development tools to look at the JS code that's causing the error, here's what the contents of the JS file are said to be: exactly the same HTML that my index.php file is returning. (So, no wonder there's JavaScript errors being generated.)

So, what that tells me is, the call from my HTML code to foo.js is being redirected, and the contents of index.php is being returned instead of the contents of foo.js. But it ONLY happens when I have multiple elements in my URL.

BTW, it's not just JS that isn't working properly ... any links to CSS files will run into the same problem (they get returned as the HTML from index.php). So it seems to be the linking and returning another file, rather than what type of file it is.

So ... I'm stumped. Is there some trick to htaccess that I need to be using, that I'm not? Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: No sooner did I post this than I thought to try using site-relative or absolute paths to all resources ... which SOLVED THE PROBLEM. However ... is there any way to use relative links in such a situation? Requiring only root-relative links in a routed page seems pretty kludgy.

Comment: First of all, congrats on realizing what the issue here is yourself (many people starting to use mod_rewrite don’t). Now, as for using paths that refer to the domain root to refer to external resources – that is quite a common practice. If you want to be able to keep your project flexible, in that you could move it to deeper subdirectory at some point, the recommendation is to configure a base path as a constant or something the like, that you can use as prefix to every such path you need to output. […]

Comment: […] For a start, that can simply be `/` – and then you simply output that as `<script src="<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>js/foo.js"></script>` dynamically via PHP wherever you need to refer to an external resource. Should you need to move the whole project to a folder, say `/foobar/` at some point, then you simply change the value of that constant, and all your dynamically generated paths will adapt, `/js/foo.js` will become `/foobar/js/foo.js`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough details here. I guess it's time for me to embrace root-relative links. And as you say, the whole BASE_PATH constant will work there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>A Test Page Goes Here</title>
    <script src="/foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, what I discovered (and what the other comments mentioned). Thanks, everybody for the responses. If I'm using slashes in my URL, even though it's going to be redirected, those slashes become part of how document-relative links are determined by the browser.